# Why does Selenium not read the .text attribute of a <label> text?

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

I'm wondering why Selenium can't read the text of a label tag, even though `get_attribute("innerHTML")` returns the correct content.

```
<label style="position: absolute;">TextContent</label>
```

This is the `outerHTML` (unfortunately, I cannot publish more code for security reasons).

`TextContent` is the inner one, but `.text` is an empty string.

On every other element, `.text` works perfectly fine.

Thanks for your help,

Nico

Comment: May be the element not visible on the page. Can you check the parent node of the element whether any attribute hidden is true.

Comment: Yup, that is the issue. Thank you so much, I didn't knew that .text only works when it is visible but innerHTML works every time.